# iText CopyAsFormXObject PdfException

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

As I am processing my main pdf file and when I get to page 2 I start to read this Adobe Illustrator. I get this `PdfException` at the line `origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(aiDocument);` about the indirect object. I am not sure why I am getting this error because its a different file.

> iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException: 'Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.'

```
const float imageX = 111.318f, imageY = 130.791f;
//const float imageWidth = 755.454f, imageHeight = 432.094f;
    
string aifilePath = @"PathToAIFile.ai";    
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(aifilePath);
using (var aiStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (var aimodifiedaiStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   var aiReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(aiStream);
   var aiDocument = new PdfDocument(aiReader, new PdfWriter(aimodifiedaiStream));
   PdfPage origPage = aiDocument.GetFirstPage();
   PdfFormXObject  aifForm = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(aiDocument);
   canvasPage.AddXObjectAt(aifForm, imageX, imageY);
}
```

Updated with two PdfDocument

```
const float imageX = 111.318f, imageY = 130.791f;
//const float imageWidth = 755.454f, imageHeight = 432.094f;

string aifilePath = @"PathToAIFile.ai";    
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(aifilePath);
using (var aiStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (var aimodifiedaiStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   var aisourceReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(aiStream);
   var pdfsourceDocument = new PdfDocument(aisourceReader, new PdfWriter(aimodifiedaiStream));
   var pdftargetDocument = new PdfDocument(aisourceReader);
   PdfPage origPage = aiDocument.GetFirstPage();
   PdfFormXObject  aifForm = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(aiDocument);
   canvasPage.AddXObjectAt(aifForm, imageX, imageY);
}
```

Updated with pdftargetDocument has a writer and pdfsourceDocument with just PdfReader still getting the error `Cannot copy to document opened in reading mode.'`

```
using (var aiStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (var aimodifiedaiStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
   var aisourceReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));
   var aitargetReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));
                
   var pdfsourceDocument = new PdfDocument(aisourceReader);
   var pdftargetDocument = new PdfDocument(aitargetReader, new PdfWriter(aimodifiedaiStream));
   PdfPage origPage = pdfsourceDocument.GetFirstPage();

   PdfFormXObject  aifForm = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfsourceDocument);
   canvasPage.AddXObjectAt(aifForm, imageX, imageY);
   pdfsourceDocument.Close();
   pdftargetDocument.Close();
   }
```

Comment: You copy a page from `aiDocument` as form XObject to `aiDocument`. And clearly `aiDocument` is being written, it has a `PdfWriter` in its constructor. You can only copy pages from a `PdfDocument` constructed without a `PdfWriter`.

Comment: but I would still get an error about `Cannot copy to document opened in reading mode.` Do I need another object?

Comment: Indeed, the source `PdfDocument` must not be written to and the destination `PdfDocument` must be written to. Thus, they cannot be the same object.

Comment: sorry I still not sure that I understand I need two `PdfDocument` one that is being used by the reader `var aiDocument = new PdfDocument(aiReader);`. And another one that is being used in the `CopyAsFormXObject`?

Comment: Concerning your code update - I'm fairly sure you cannot use the same `PdfReader` instance in two `PdfDocuments`. Furthermore, the _target_ needs a writer, not the _source_. Then you forget to close `PdfDocument` instances. And there are a number of undefined variables.

Comment: I am still getting the `Cannot copy to document opened in reading mode.`

Comment: I updated my code but still getting error

Comment: You copy from `pdfsourceDocument` to `pdfsourceDocument`. So you still copy from a document into itself. Start copying from source to target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Summing up my comments as an answer...*

You copy a page from the `PdfDocument aiDocument` as form XObject to the same `aiDocument`.

Clearly `aiDocument` is being written, it has a `PdfWriter` in its constructor. But the iText API only allows copying pages from a `PdfDocument` constructed without a `PdfWriter`.

Furthermore, you can only copy to a `PdfDocument` that is written to, i.e. that is constructed with a `PdfWriter`. Thus, you cannot copy from a document into itself.

Thus, you need different `PdfDocument` instances as source and target of the copy process.

The source `PdfDocument` instance is generated with only a `PdfReader`, no `PdfWriter`. The target `PdfDocument` instance is generated with a `PdfWriter`. If the target also is generated with a `PdfReader` depends on your precise use case: Do you want to add the XObject to an existing document, or do you want to add it to an empty document without any prior content.

Comment: I would like to add it to a existing  `canvasPage`, with this I would also need a another `PdfReader` object.